Is there any software package to find the vertices of convex polytope where the inequality constraints are bounded by variable?
I know of this package lcon2vert that computes vertices from given inequality and equality constraints describing a bounded polyhedron. Here the bounds of constraints only accept numerical values, i.e. $2x_{1}+3x_{2} \le 5$. Now, how can we obtain vertices if the constraint is bounded by a variable where the variable itself is bounded to keep the polyhedron bounded ? i.e. $2x_{1}+3x_{2} \le \alpha $ where $0 \le \alpha \le 1$.
 I am only seeking answers for bounded convex polyhedra.

Maybe you should make $\alpha$ another variable, and then use your existing package.

If you write it as $2x_1+3x_2 - \alpha \leq 0$ and $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\alpha \leq 1$, this is in a format that your package can work with

Yeah, it works. Thank you
